# Running python 3.7 on miniconda on raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, miniconda

I want to use python 3.7 in raspberry pi through miniconda but surfing, I got to know that miniconda provides python version upto 3.4. Some sources said to use berryconda, which I installed but still the `conda info` states my python version is 3.6. I tried to install python 3.7 through `conda install python=3.7`. But as u might have guessed that didnt work as well. I do have python 3.7 manually installed but I don't think there is a way to make conda use that version (please correct me if I'm wrong and tell me how).

I want to create an environment with these dependencies, but it seems I'm stuck on the first step (python 3.7):

name: yolov4-cpu

dependencies:

- python==3.7
- pip
- matplotlib
- opencv
- pip:

  - opencv-python==4.1.1.26
  - lxml
  - tqdm
  - tensorflow==2.3.0rc0
  - absl-py
  - easydict
  - pillow

Is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: Miniconda definitely supports all recent versions of Python, including 3.7. How are you installing Miniconda? There are several installers listed in the official source: https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/

Comment: I dont exactly remember how...but I'm thinking to remove and try it once again..Can u point out which installer should I get, keeping in mind that i need python 3.7 and tensorflow 2.3 at the least...

Comment: or can I update the conda I have through terminal...I just checked...I'm having conda version 3.16. Does the latest version of conda satisfy my requirements that i have mentioned above?

Comment: That version is very old. Since everything is out of date, I recommend a fresh install of Miniconda.

Comment: okay noted..I'm going for Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-x86_64.sh Lets see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: @MattThompson I did try out this version but turns out this version of miniconda won't work on raspiberry pi. Can u specifically point/send the link for the latest miniconda version that would work on raspberry pi..thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: try without using conda, conda in raspi does work but I think it limits the raspi to a certain version of libraries which miniconda offers. In conclusion, try some other method except conda.